# How to update state when redirecting React Navite?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

First of all, I apologize for my English.

I created a menu with React Tab Navigation. I have placed the Home screen in the menu. After login, I return to the menu screen. If there's a token, I'm trading it. But the expo doesn't see it until it renews.

componentDidMount or componentWillMount does not work. Is there any other solution?

*LoginScreen.js*

```
await AsyncStorage.setItem('userId', userId);
await AsyncStorage.setItem('fullName', fullName);
await AsyncStorage.setItem('email', email);
await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', token);

Alert.alert(
  'Hoşgeldiniz',
  'Başarılı bir şekilde giriş yaptınız!',
  [
      { text: 'Yönlendir', onPress: () => this.props.navigation.navigate('Menu') }
  ]
);
```

*MenuScreen.js*

```
componentDidMount() {
  this._retrieveData();
}

_retrieveData = async () => {
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');

  if (token !== null) {        
    this.setState({ token: token });
  }else {
    this.logout();
  }
};
```

*TabNavigator*

```
const MenuStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Menu: MenuScreen,
    Login: LoginScreen,
    Register: RegisterScreen
  },
  config
);

const tabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  HomeStack,
  CampaignStack,
  MenuStack
});

tabNavigator.path = '';

export default tabNavigator;
```

Comment: did you try componentDidUpdate? Can you post the tab structure code?

Comment: I added @Auticcat

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

I am just modifying your code a little. Can you try this:

*MenuScreen.js*

```
componentDidMount() {
  this._retrieveData();
}

_retrieveData = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.getItem('token', async (err, result) => {
        if (result) {
            this.setState({ token: token });
        } else {
            this.logout();
        }
    })
}
```

**Solution 2:**

Also since you just need token to set in you **MenuScreen.js**, you can pass the token as props.
Something like this:

*LoginScreen.js*

```
await AsyncStorage.setItem('userId', userId); 
await AsyncStorage.setItem('fullName', fullName); 
await AsyncStorage.setItem('email', email); 
await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', token);

Alert.alert(   
'Hoşgeldiniz',   
'Başarılı bir şekilde giriş yaptınız!',   
[
    { text: 'Yönlendir', onPress: () =>  this.props.navigation.navigate('Menu', {passedToken: token })}   
]);
```

*MenuScreen.js*

```
componentDidMount() {
  this._retrieveData();
}

_retrieveData = async () => {
    const token = this.props.navigation.state.params.passedToken;
    if (token) {
        this.setState({ token: token });
    } else {
        this.logout();
    }
}
```